How to setup routing on Windows machine with one ethernet card to have access to 2 network?
I have 2 gateways:

one is a router that give access to the internet (192.168.0.1)
second gives access to private network that have application and resources (172.16.28.1)

How to make Windows machine to have access to both the internet and resources on the private network? I cant configure 172.16.28.1 gateway since i dont have permission to configure it

How are the networks physically set up? It can be as simple as adding a route on your main gateway to send traffic for 172.16.X.Y through 172.16.28.1

Its a simple network, 5 pcs, 2 gateways (one is a router that gives the internet and i have access to configure it) , 1 L2 switch.

Ideally i want machines to have 172.16.x.x ip address, and make routing so they have access to the internet

Can you add some more detail, like what is the other gateway, and why not make it a single network if the PCs should have internet access? For example, if everything is sharing the same L2 switch, then you could add an additional 172 IP to the interface in windows

The 172.16.28.1 gateway give access to web applications, it's a juniper hardware. That's exactly what I did for now I've added secondary 172 IP, but people(on the internet) says im an idiot, it's bad practice and I should do routing instead. I'm confused because I'm not that experienced

If it's working for you, then it's fine. It can be better to do on the router so you don't have to manually enter on each PC for example. That kind of solution doesn't work in certain cases like when the networks are more separated
